# Android device - C++ OpenGL 2: eglCreateWindowSurface invalid

Tags: c++, android, mobile, opengl-es2

I am trying to debug and run OGLES on Native C++ in my Android device in order to implement a native 3D game for mobile smart phones. The point is that I got an error and see no reason for that. Here is the line from the code that the debugger complains:

```
    mSurface = eglCreateWindowSurface(mDisplay, 
                                      lConfig, mApplication->window, NULL);
```

And this is the error message:

```
    Invalid arguments ' Candidates are: 
        void * eglCreateWindowSurface(void *, void *, 
                                      unsigned long int, const int *) '
```

--x--

Here is the declaration:

```
    android_app* mApplication;

    EGLDisplay mDisplay;
    EGLint lFormat, lNumConfigs, lErrorResult;
    EGLConfig lConfig;
    // Defines display requirements. 16bits mode here.
    const EGLint lAttributes[] = {
        EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT,
        EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 5, EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 6, EGL_RED_SIZE, 5,
        EGL_SURFACE_TYPE, EGL_WINDOW_BIT, EGL_RENDER_BUFFER, EGL_BACK_BUFFER,
        EGL_NONE
    };
    // Retrieves a display connection and initializes it.
    packt_Log_debug("Connecting to the display.");
    mDisplay = eglGetDisplay(EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);
    if (mDisplay == EGL_NO_DISPLAY) goto ERROR;
    if (!eglInitialize(mDisplay, NULL, NULL)) goto ERROR;
    // Selects the first OpenGL configuration found.
    packt_Log_debug("Selecting a display config.");
    if(!eglChooseConfig(mDisplay, lAttributes, &lConfig, 1,
        &lNumConfigs) || (lNumConfigs <= 0)) goto ERROR;
    // Reconfigures the Android window with the EGL format.
    packt_Log_debug("Configuring window format.");
    if (!eglGetConfigAttrib(mDisplay, lConfig,
        EGL_NATIVE_VISUAL_ID, &lFormat)) goto ERROR;
    ANativeWindow_setBuffersGeometry(mApplication->window, 0, 0, lFormat);
    // Creates the display surface.
    packt_Log_debug("Initializing the display.");
    mSurface = eglCreateWindowSurface(mDisplay, lConfig, mApplication->window, NULL);
```

--x--

Hope someone here can shed some light on it.

Comment: If your problem lays on arguments, why didn't you paste the declarations?

Comment: @kaoD .. just posted it.

Comment: You're missing mDisplay declaration, but I guess it's not a pointer, like lFormat, right?

Comment: @kaoD .. just posted it.

Comment: Yep, it's not a pointer. Just check my answer.

Comment: @kaoD... please see my comment to your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `lFormat` (and possibly `mDisplay` too) is not a pointer. You need to pass it as a pointer, using the reference operator (`&`) You might need to cast it too to match the `void*` on the function signature.

Comment: I tried your suggestion ::        mSurface = eglCreateWindowSurface(&mDisplay,
                 &lConfig,
                 mApplication->window,
                 NULL); /// but the problem did go away yet.

Comment: @ThreaderSlash you didn't post `mApplication->window` declaration yet. You might have to cast NULL too (I'm not aware if C++ or any of your includes have NULL as a `const int *`)

Comment: @kaoD... sorry for that. Now it is posted.

Comment: @ThreaderSlash I don't need `mApplication`, I need `window`...

Comment: this is the window: struct android_app {ANativeWindow* window;};
android_app* mApplication;

Comment: `ANativeWindow*` is not `unsigned long int`. It's a pointer too... how's it ever gona work?

Comment: @kaoD... Replacing 'mApplication->window' for 'EGLNativeWindowType window' solved the problem. Thanks for pointing the right direction!